# What Schottky diode would be contemporary to the 2N2222 transistor?

Tags: diodes, history

I'm working on a "retro" discrete design that is meant to use components that were available in the mid-1960s, but are still available today. The main building block I'm using is PN2222 - a cheaper packaged 2N2222 that got introduced in 1962 (!). A 60 year availability of that part is hard to beat. But what about Schottky diodes? What common Schottky part numbers were introduced around that time (say 1960-1969)?

Comment: Unless you really need the low forward voltage, stick with silicon diodes (1N914, newer 1N4148) ... Schottky diodes were more like a 1980s thing. Or for low Vf and 1960s availability, look at Germanium diodes (1N34?) Note 1N denotes a 2-lead device, 2N a 3-lead device etc so these are all part of the same numbering system.

Comment: @BrianDrummond 74S (Schottky) TTL was introduced in 1971. i3101 64-bit RAM used Schottky diodes and was introduced in 1969. I'm pretty sure someone must have been offering those as discrete parts in the 1960s. You could certainly buy them in the very early 1970s.

Comment: OK I was looking more at common availability rather than introduction dates. But still : early-mid 60s was the latter end of the Ge era.